# Breakpoint within @property is not working - PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, breakpoints

I have a property to a python class, such as below.  I have a breakpoint on the `return due_date` line but when I run debug it does not stop.  There's something wrong with it and I need to troubleshoot.  When I instantiate the class, the `due_date` object in pycharm shows a traceback instead of failing the program too, which I would like to understand.

```py
    @property
    def due_date(self):
        """Find the due date of this account."""
        due_date = json.loads(self.category["note"])["due_day"]
        due_date = f"{datetime.now().year}-{datetime.now().month}-{due_date}"
        return due_date
```

Comment: If the error is happening before the `return` statement, you'll never hit the breakpoint.

Comment: Try putting the breakpoint on the first statement, then you can step through it.